# OctoberCMS - Is it possible to do a simple math in backend?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

So i have a fields of total_quantity and order_quantity in the backend which are from the database. Is it possible to subtract these two value and the result is displayed in a new fields? Basically the result fields is name as left_quantity and not in the database.

Comment: purpose of that is just to show information , correct ?

Comment: yes just to show the result of subtraction

Comment: Do you want to run a PHP code as described in [Running PHP code on pages](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/running-php-code-on-pages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `partial field type` for this.

check below demo you can use it to create own partial to show exactly what you want. For demo I already created one table, with field title.

> Now, I want to do some `operation/modification on title` and show it just like you want.

> `fields.yaml` file

```yaml
fields:
    title:
        label: Title
        span: auto
        type: text
    other_title:
        label: Modification
        span: auto
        type: partial
        path: $/hardik/demo/controllers/items/_my_field.htm
```

make sure to replace your `partial path`

> `_my_field.htm` file

```php
<?php
    // for new record
    $data = 'New record';

    if($model->title) {
        $data = 'Modified ' . $model->title;
    }

?>
<input 
    type="text" 
    value="<?= $data ?>" 
    class="form-control" 
    autocomplete="on" 
/>
```

Here we are checking if we are creating record it means `$model` is not having title so we just show `New Record`. if we have already saved record and we have data in `title` we perform `modification`.

#### Output

> For new records

[image: new_record]

> For already created records

[image: already_exist_image]

if any doubts please comment